# What's an alternative to Truecrypt with exact same feature set?

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption, truecrypt

Does any software for Ubuntu exist that does the exact same thing as Truecrypt? I know there is a version of Truecrypt for all platforms, but the developers abandoned the project.

Please don't just start posting encryption software that can do the encryption this or that way, I am asking for the exact same thing.

For Windows there is "safe house explorer".

Comment: Is it also your requirement that it can handle your currently existing Truecrypt volumes just like with the original Truecrypt before it got abandoned? Because the alternative you mention for Windows does not do that, but you're also asking for an exact same product. Also, it lacks features like being free software. Please [edit] your question to include more specifics to your requirements.

Comment: I am asking for truecrypt like software, not some random encryption software, so no, not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcplay claims to be able to read/write Truecrypt volumes.  The package exists in the Ubuntu repository.  I haven't done much with it, but it did fail on my one attempt to open an old volume originally created by Truecrypt. Maybe the volume it too old, I will eventually create a new one and see if that is readable in tcplay.